# variadic function in C

Tags: c, variadic-functions

1) Why code under `/* test1 */` chunk do not print out anything, but code under `/* test2 */` print correctly?

2) How to use `va_arg(va, char*)` in `/* test 1 */` code chunk.

---

```
void rdfDBG(int dbglevel, const char *fmt, ...) {

    va_list va;

#if 1 /* test 1 */
    char* logbuf;

    if ((logbuf = calloc(0x0, LOGBUFFERSIZE))== NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n"); /* 1. Is there a better way instead of using fprintf? */

    va_start(va, fmt);
    (void) vsnprintf(logbuf, strlen(logbuf), fmt, va); /* 2. print nothing */
    va_end(va);

    free(logbuf);
#endif

#if 0 /* test 2 */
    va_start(va, fmt);
    vprintf(fmt, va); /* 2. print "pinfile pings6.txt" */
    va_end(va);
#endif


}


int ptInitialize(){

    char* pinfile;
    pinfile = "pings6.txt";

    rdfDBG(kINFO, "pinfile %s\n", pinfile);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code under `/* test 1 */` doesn't print anything because the `vsnprint()` function doesn't print to stdout; it just writes its output into the provided buffer.

It's pure luck if the code didn't crash, though, because the line:

```
if ((logbuf = calloc(0x0, LOGBUFFERSIZE))== NULL)
```

actually tells `calloc()` to allocate 0 bytes of memory.  Because of this, I don't think it's guaranteed that the memory `logbuf` points at is zeroed either -- so not only is your buffer zero bytes long, but calling `strlen()` on it could crash or give you an invalid result.

Also, the second argument to `vsnprint()` is supposed to be the size of the buffer, that is the size you've allocated for `logbuf`, not the length of any string already in it; it's to limit the number of bytes written to the buffer to avoid a buffer overrun.

So to get everything working, you need to change:

```
    if ((logbuf = calloc(0x0, LOGBUFFERSIZE))== NULL)
```

..to..

```
    if ((logbuf = calloc(1, LOGBUFFERSIZE))== NULL)
```

..to allocate space for 1 item of `LOGBUFFERSIZE` bytes.  And also change:

```
(void) vsnprintf(logbuf, strlen(logbuf), fmt, va);
```

..to..

```
vsnprintf(logbuf, LOGBUFFERSIZE, fmt, va);
```

..to pass it the size of your buffer and remove the useless `(void)` cast.  And also add a line to print `logbuf`, such as:

```
fputs(logbuf, stderr);
```

after it.

Comment: thanks. I have apparently misunderstood the correct usage of calloc and vsnprintf.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
vsnprintf(logbuf, strlen(logbuf)...
```

Will never format anything, because `logbuf` is all zeros (having been allocated by `calloc`, and so `strlen` will return zero, which makes vsnprintf never format anything because you told it to print at most zero characters.

Comment: Even after fixing that problem, you still won't get anything printed because `vsnprintf` doesn't print. It puts the result into `logbuf`, but you never print `logbuf`.

Comment: Are you out of your mind?  Changing it to malloc was not the solution--now you are using uninitialized memory.  You need to pass LOGBUFFERSIZE as the second argument rather than strlen(logbuf).

Comment: if ((logbuf = malloc(LOGBUFFERSIZE))== NULL)
        fprintf(stderr, "out of memory\n"); 

    va_start(va, fmt);
    (void) vsnprintf(logbuf, LOGBUFFERSIZE, fmt, va);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", logbuf);
    va_end(va);

Comment: Three upvotes? Really? This answer is patently incorrect. Dmitri's answer is correct.

Comment: How is it incorrect?  I will readily admit that it is incomplete, as I see now there were actually many problems with the code, but if I said something actually wrong I would like to know what.

Comment: You said that `vsnprintf` won't print anything because the string is all zeroes. This is incorrect because as @Raymond mentioned, `vsnprintf` doesn't print anyway. The fact that it won't print anything has nothing to do with the parameters given.